# Splitting an alphanumeric string using regex is not working

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to split the words on two conditions
1) by space
2) by word - starting with 'n' and ending with 't' and contains numeric at last

basically a payment term

Following test case should pass in my case. Can someone explain why regex is not working?

```
String[] splitedWords3 = new String[] {"payment","term","nt","40","net","00","net", "30"};
Assertions.assertThat("payment term nt40 net00 net30".split("n[a-z]*t\\d+|\\S+")).isEqualTo(splitedWords3);
```

Comment: What do you think the expression `n[a-z]*t\d+` will match? If you break it down it's "the character n, any number of lowercase characters, the character t and finally a sequence of one or more digits". This would match `nt40`, `net00` and `net30` only, which clearly wouldn't fit your expectations - and those seem to wrong anyway: `String.split()` will _remove_ the matches from the resulting array so you should get the result `{"payment term ", " ", " "}` - clearly this doesn't match the expected array.

Comment: You'll also need to refine your requirements: "split by space" is fine - you seem to want to get rid of spaces (your expression doesn't reflect that though) - but what about "split by word ..." - your test indicates you don't want to split _by_ word but you want to keep the words and split the `n....t` part from the digits (you'd need to match the zero-width position here, i.e. use some look-around expressions).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do `split`. You should match what you want and keep it in a `List` like this code:

```
final String regex = "\\b(n\\w*t)(\\d+)\\b|(\\S+)";
final String string = "payment term nt40 net00 net30";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
   if (matcher.group(3) != null) {
      words.add(matcher.group(3));
   } else {
      words.add(matcher.group(1));
      words.add(matcher.group(2));
   }
}

System.out.println(words);
```

**Output:**

```
[payment, term, nt, 40, net, 00, net, 30]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MiAV2M/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(n\w*t)`: Match a word that starts with `n` until we get `t` and capture in group #1
- `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits at end of word and capture in group #2
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `|`: OR
- `(\S+)`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters and capture in group #3

Comment: is there any there way than using group?

Comment: In Java, probably not. What's the problem in using groups?